# How do I import turtle in Spyder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am new to Python (and coding in general) and have recently downloaded the Spyder IDE. I was able to import numpy, math, and matplotlib.pyplot successfully using the code

```py
import numpy as np
import math as math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

However, when I try to import turtle (following [this tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html)) using `from turtle import *`, an orange triangle shows up next to my code reading `Code analysis` and `'from turtle import \*' used; unable to detect undefined names *(pyflakes E)*`. I tried to use `forward(100)` to check if turtle imported correctly, but running that gave me the error

```py
TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/tcl8.6 /Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/lib/tcl8.6 /Applications/Spyder.app/lib/tcl8.6 /Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/library /Applications/Spyder.app/library /Applications/Spyder.app/tcl8.6.12/library /Applications/tcl8.6.12/library



This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
```

Looking up "Tcl" python lead me to [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#module-tkinter), which told me to run `python -m tkinter` in my Terminal. Doing that opened up a small window with buttons reading "Click me!" and "QUIT" and gave me the warning

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Please don't rely on it. Set TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 to suppress this warning.
2024-03-18 15:00:55.904 Python[8386:430980] WARNING: Secure coding is automatically enabled for restorable state! However, not on all supported macOS versions of this application. Opt-in to secure coding explicitly by implementing NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState:.
```

I also tried to install turtle (and Tcl) using the commands

```
python3 -m pip install -U turtle
python3 -m pip install -U Tcl
```

in my terminal. Installing Tcl worked fine as far as I can tell, but when I tried to install turtle I got the message

```
Collecting turtle
  Using cached turtle-0.0.2.tar.gz (11 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [22 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/4r/z64sp8193pj4msr2x3xb3wpm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-dljsc7mu/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/4r/z64sp8193pj4msr2x3xb3wpm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-dljsc7mu/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/4r/z64sp8193pj4msr2x3xb3wpm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-dljsc7mu/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "/private/var/folders/4r/z64sp8193pj4msr2x3xb3wpm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-dljsc7mu/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 40
          except ValueError, ve:
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      SyntaxError: multiple exception types must be parenthesized
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

In case it is useful, I have a mac with macOS 14.1, and at the bottom of my Spyder window, it says that I have Spyder 5.5.3 and Python 3.10.11

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try either of the suggestions [on this page](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/How-to-run-turtle-scripts-within-Spyder) - does either of those work for you? Note that if you installed Spyder with the standalone installer, it uses its own Python interpreter not the system Python, so running `pip install` commands in the terminal won't affect Spyder's Python - see [here](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-packages-installer). However if you didn't get an error at `from turtle import *` in Spyder then that isn't the problem.

Comment: Note that the code analysis warning is only a warning, and it's telling you that when you do an `import *` the code analyser (pyflakes) can't tell what will be imported and therefore can't check your code properly. It's good practice to avoid `import *` but it's not the cause of your issue here.